# AngularJS state next button

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a next button in a nested form using AngularJS states. Here is my setup as is:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
    .state('step', {
        url: '/step',
        templateUrl: 'form.html',
        count: '0',
        controller: 'formController'
    })
    .state('step.1', {
        url: '/1',
        count: '1',
        templateUrl: 'form-1.html'
    })
    .state('step.2', {
        url: '/2',
        count: '2',
        templateUrl: 'form-2.html'
    })
    .state('step.3', {
        url: '/3',
        count: '3',
        templateUrl: 'form-3.html'
    })
    .state('step.4', {
        url: '/4',
        count: '4',
        templateUrl: 'form-4.html'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/step/1');
})
```

To navigate between the states I am using an ng-click function:

```
$scope.nextStep = $state.current.count;

$scope.nextStepCount = function() {
    $scope.count = $scope.nextStep + 1;
    $state.go('step.' + $scope.count);
}
```

When i click the next button it changes the current route on "step.1" to "step.11".

Comment: Concatenation of a string rather than addition of numbers is what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks JMK, this seems to work like a charm:

```
$scope.nextStepCount = function() {
    $scope.count = parseInt($state.current.count) + 1;
    $state.go('step.' + $scope.count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace:

```
$scope.count = $scope.nextStep + 1;
```

With:

```
$scope.count = parseInt($scope.nextStep) + 1;
```

Javascript is treating nextStep as a string so adding 1 onto the end of that string.